# Need a value from a Generated text based on configuration file in Unix

Tags: unix

I am having a text file generated based on configuration files.
Configuration file will have the fields that i am going to generate.
Like below,

1)Configuration.txt
account,name,serial_no

2)generated_file.txt

```
414d51204d5150525447575648415050529a6af298c,ß,200296125220140707123915  ,+0763
414d51204d5150525447575648415050529a6af2996,º,200303740520140707174224  ,+0657
414d51204d5150525447575648415050529a6af298b,|,200349107120140707120811  ,+0422
414d51204d5150525447575648415050529a6af298d,é,200510041820140707130954  ,+0664
```

So in generated_file.txt always account number will have some junk value like this

414d51204d5150525447575648415050529a6af298c,ß, -- one seperate field (like ,%,  ,¥,).
so what i need is like field 2 and fields 3 omitting field 1 having junk values.

```
Desired Output
200296125220140707123915  ,+0763
200303740520140707174224  ,+0657
```

I am able to get that value by this command.

but if the number of field in configuration file got changed as below. I have 
to change the query in script as below. Which i do want to do manually.

```
config.txt
account,name,serial_no,marks
```

What i need is like a generic command which will take number of fields in config.txt
and take all the fields omitting field1(account which is having junk value).

Thanks

Comment: Configuration.txt
account,name,serial_no

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print column 3 and 4:

```
cut -d, -f3,4 generated_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk script : `awk -F , '{ for(col=3;col<=NF;col++){printf $col ","} print ""}'` 

Example:

```
Vikram:PROGS admin$ cat b.txt 
414d51204d5150525447575648415050529a6af298c,ß,200296125220140707123915  ,+0763, joy, HR
414d51204d5150525447575648415050529a6af2996,º,200303740520140707174224  ,+0657, bob
414d51204d5150525447575648415050529a6af298b,|,200349107120140707120811  ,+0422
414d51204d5150525447575648415050529a6af298d,é,200510041820140707130954  ,+0664

Vikram:PROGS admin$ cat b.txt | awk -F , '{ for(col=3;col<=NF;col++){printf $col ","} print ""}'
200296125220140707123915  ,+0763, joy, HR,
200303740520140707174224  ,+0657, bob,
200349107120140707120811  ,+0422,
200510041820140707130954  ,+0664,
```